# SQL anywhere 5 error

Tags: sqlanywhere

I have a below block of code calling from c language.

do_connect();
db_find_engine(&sqlca,NULL);

//EXEC SQL CONNECT "athena" IDENTIFIED BY "amci";

dbpp_connect_40( (sqlcaptr), &__SQLV_sql_1, __SQLV_sql_2, __SQLV_sql_3, SQLNULL, SQLNULL, SQLNULL );

I am getting below mentioned crash at the above line of code(dbpp_connect_40). I am not getting the problem.DB is up and running. Please help me?

Unhandled exception at 0x651054e7 in Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x9040006c.

ravi

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are linking to the correct library ? It sounds like a version mismatch.